# I have to add new item into an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

```
obj = [
    { "name": "john", "age": "25" },  
    { "name": "jose", "age": "30" }, 
    { "name": "mark", "age": "32" }
]

var country = [USA, UK, China]
```

this is my current object. I have to add country from anorther array into each item Eg:

```
obj = [
    { "name": "john", "age": "25", "country": "USA" }, 
    { "name": "jose", "age": "30", "country": "UK" }, 
    { "name": "mark", "age": "32", "country": "China" }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: tip : Your `obj` is an array of objects. How would you get an object from an array ? If found, find out how to add something to an object. Combine both and there is your answer.

Comment: The way you do this is by learning basic JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
obj = [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": "25"
  },
  {
    "name": "jose",
    "age": "30"
  },
  {
    "name": "mark",
    "age": "32"
  }
]

var country = ['usa', 'china'];


for (var i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
  obj[i].country = country[i];

}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
obj = [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": "25"
  },
  {
    "name": "jose",
    "age": "30"
  },
  {
    "name": "mark",
    "age": "32"
  }
]

var country = ["USA", "UK", "China"]
if (obj.length == country.length) {
  for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    obj[i].country = country[i];
  }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Also you need to add quotes around country names.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```js
obj = [{
    "name": "john",
    "age": "25"
  },
  {
    "name": "jose",
    "age": "30"
  },
  {
    "name": "mark",
    "age": "32"
  }
]

var country = ['USA', 'UK', 'China']


$(country).each(function(i, e) {
  obj[i].country = e;
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's iterating over the array, `i` is index, `e` is element. If you need to add a property to an object you can just assign it, so `obj[i]` will give you the object, to assign its `country` property just assign to it.

Comment: jQuery was not requested nor is it required or even advisable. Last time I looked, JavaScript itself had for loops.

Comment: @torazaburo OP doesn't say anything about not using jQuery and it's included in the tags.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the tag. However, it is nevertheless the case that using jQuery for this only to implement a loop is HUGE overkill.

Comment: @torazaburo The question has a javascript tag and it has a jQuery tag, I gave an jQuery answer, others gave a javascript answer. I don't think giving an answer for one of the tags should be down-voted. A comment like "No need to use jQuery here, there's a for loop in JS with better performance" would be my preferred way of dealing with an answer I don't agree with. Just saying.

Comment: @artm That's what my comment said, essentially. As for downvotes, there is no rule other than that someone thinks an answer is not helpful.

Comment: @torazaburo True, I don't think this answer was not helpful though, it helped OP. Anyway, I'm not trying to argue about the down-votes, just a friendly discussion with a fellow programmer.

Comment: `.each()` method isn't designed for array, you need to use `$.each()` instead:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/   Maybe that explains all the downvotes, not sure about that. From DOC: `The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object.`

Comment: @A.Wolff Do you think there's a difference? `$.each([])` and `$([]).each()` produce the same result, don't they? Is there some performance issue I'm not aware of?

Comment: @artm Working doesn't mean you should use it, e.g, i can ride my bicycle on highway BUT i shouldn't. `$(selector).each()` isn't designed for that, it works only because jQuery implement length property on set of matched element(s)

Comment: @A.Wolff Yeah, you might be right. I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: @A.Wolff On 2nd thought, $(selector) returns an array, doesn't matter if it's an array of strings or elements, it's an array. $(selector).each() shouldn't be any different than $([]).each(), both are working on an array. So does $.each([]). Am I wrong?

Comment: @artm You are quite correct indeed and checking jQuery's source, `$(selector).each()` is just an alias for `$.each()` method. So the only 'problem' of using `$([]).each()` would be the unnecessary jQuey wrapping of array element, not a big deal for sure. As a side note, `$(selector)` returns an array-like object, meaning an object with a `length` property and with some array methods, but not all AFAIK